# Prove that $x^{15}-4x^7+2x^5 - 6$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Prove $x^{15}-4x^7+2x^5 - 6$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$.

I know I've learned the process for this before but I cannot recall how the factoring works.

By the Rational Root Theorem $6$ is our only candidate. If I recall correctly I can use Fermat's Little theorem but I can't find any thing in my old notes.

If anyone can suggest a source for similar stuff, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to apply the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) in the correct way.
A polynomial $p(x)=x^m+\ldots+6\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ has a rational root iff it vanishes at some $x\in\{\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\pm 6\}$. Your polynomial does not, so it has no rational root.

Tsemo Aristide's answer is even more powerful: by Eisenstein's criterion (wrt $p=2$) your polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 4):

you can apply the Eisenstein for p=2

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion